# while using HttpURLConnection is it necessary to use disconnect()

Tags: httpurlconnection

Can anyone please explain what will be the impact if I dont use disconnect() while using HttpURLConnection. I am sending and recieving data through the connection. and closing the input and output streams. Is that enough or I should explicitely use disconnect().

```
        URL url = new URL(urlname);
        HttpURLConnection urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlconnection.setRequestMethod("POST");             
        urlconnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlconnection.setConnectTimeout(s_time);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlconnection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(postData);
        out.close();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlconnection.getInputStream()));
        String somestring;
        while ((somestring = in.readLine()) != null) {
            data += somestring;
        }
        in.close();
```

Comment: I read through the source code and there is a good deal of cleanup being done from `disconnect()`.  I can't give you an example of why closing the streams yourself is necesarily wrong, but you should probably use the method to handle this for you.

Comment: Does that mean till I do disconnect connection will be still open? Having an issue where my process gets disconnected with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: added code in answer